# query database using variable in eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to query for records using eloquent.

this works fine:

```
    $xs = X::all()->where('y_id', 1);
    return view('x', compact('xs'));
```

but when i try to pass a variable:

```
    $xs = X::all()->where('y_id', $id);
    return view('x', compact('xs'));
```

it returns empty array!

how can I do this query?

Comment: add `->get();` at the end of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should be

```
 $xs = X::where('y_id', $id)->get();
```

all() returns all the records without any condition 
if you use a condition do a get() after all conditions queries